# SUM from 2 different table based on the ID group by from third table returning double value than expected value

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, distinct-values

I am having below Tables

**1. Material Unit:**

```
id | material_unit
1  | Nos.
2  | lts
```

**2. Material Table:**

```
id | Material_name
1  | bricks
2  | Cement
```

**3. Grn Table:**

```
id | material_id | qty | unit
1  | 1           | 100 |   1
2  | 2           | 500 |   1
3  | 2           | 100 |   1
4  | 1           | 200 |   1
```

**4. Consumption table:**

```
id | material_id | qty | unit
1  | 1           | 50  |   1
2  | 1           | 50  |   1
3  | 2           | 100 |   1
4  | 2           | 200 |   1
```

Results expected is as below:

```
Material Name | Unit | Total Qty | Total Consumed Qty | Stock
Bricks        | Nos. | 300       | 100                | 200
Cement        | Nos. | 600       | 300                | 300
```

So on above results Total Qty is to be fetched from Grn Table and Total Consumed Qty from Consumption Table and Stock is difference of both and should be Group By Material_id.

Below query returns SUM of the values from GRN and Consumption table but it multiples the SUM with the No. of entries in the consumption table.

What mistake i am doing, can someone please help to figure out my mistake.

```
SELECT sm.material_name as 'Material Name', mu.material_unit as 'Material Unit', sum(g.qty) as 'GRN Qty', sum(c.qty) as 'Consumed Qty', SUM(g.qty) - SUM(c.qty) as 'Stock' from grn g 
JOIN material_table sm ON g.material_id = sm.id
JOIN material_unit_table mu ON g.unit_id = mu.id
JOIN consumption c ON c.material_id = g.material_id

group by g.material_id
```

Comment: Is there an error? Shouldn't `Stock` for `Bricks` be 200?

Comment: Yes @Marko you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You consumption doubles the number of rows, so by summing the quantidy before joining corrects the numbers.

```
SELECT
MAX(sm.material_name) as 'Material Name'
,  MAX(mu.material_unit) as 'Material Unit'
, sum(g.qty) as 'GRN Qty'
, sum(c.qty) as 'Consumed Qty'
, SUM(g.qty) - SUM(c.qty) as 'Stock' 
from  grn g 
inner JOIN material_table sm ON g.material_id = sm.id
inner JOIN material_unit_table mu ON g.unit = mu.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT `material_id`, SUM(`qty`) qty, `unit` FROM consumption GROUP BY  `material_id`,`unit`) c ON c.material_id = g.material_id
GROUP BY g.material_id
```

example  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a19b0f5a7ba08c5e9dbb0cbf85d2a27

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is due to grn table is your origin table, so the select gets a line for each row in the table. Make material_table your first table and join the rest of them to this, using its ID to make the join with the rest of tables.

Pls, try this version and let me know if it works properly (consider it may contain an error, i've written it into a notepad)

```
SELECT sm.material_name as 'Material Name', mu.material_unit as 'Material Unit', sum(g.qty) as 'GRN Qty', sum(c.qty) as 'Consumed Qty', SUM(g.qty) - SUM(c.qty) as 'Stock' 
FROM material_table sm 
JOIN grn g ON g.material_id = sm.id
JOIN material_unit_table mu ON g.unit_id = mu.id
JOIN consumption c ON c.material_id = sm.material_id
GROUP BY by sm.material_id
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for prompt help but it is still giving the double value. Means the output is the same as the query used by me.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Grn AS (
    SELECT
        material_id,
        unit,
        SUM(qty) AS 'Total Qty'
    FROM grn
    GROUP BY
        material_id,
        unit
),
Consumption AS (
    SELECT
        material_id,
        SUM(qty) AS 'Consumed Qty'
    FROM consumption
    GROUP BY
        material_id
)
SELECT
    m.Material_name AS 'Material Name',
    u.Material_unit AS Unit,
    g.[Total Qty],
    c.[Consumed Qty],
    g.[Total Qty] - c.[Consumed Qty] AS Stock
FROM Grn g
    INNER JOIN Consumption c ON g.material_id = c.material_id
    INNER JOIN material_unit_table u ON g.unit_id = u.Id
    INNER JOIN material_table m ON g.material_id = m.Id
```

This query will give desired result.

Bottom line is to remove `material_id` duplicates in `grn` and `consumption` tables. This way joining table `consumption` and `grn` by `material_id` won't give duplicates.

**Note**: In order for this to work, in `grn` table every material needs to have only one unit.